# Internet Explorer 9 Installer for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility, internet-explorer-9, installer

As part of my standard troubleshooting for a user's issue with a webapp, I uninstalled their version of IE9 x64 by locating the original update in Windows Updates. Now I can't seem to find an installer that will work to get the program back.

The option to select it in Windows Features has disappeared as well since I uninstalled it.

Microsoft only gives you the option to download it for Vista or Server 2008 for development purposes.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx

Any other 3rd-party link I've found looks like something that would be loaded with malware.

Our office requires use of IE9 for compatibility purposes with our corporate webapps.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to downvote this for not already having an accessible copy of a vital app in-house, or for not having updated the corporate apps to at least IE 11 for security reasons.

Comment: I don't know why their apps need IE9 or why they haven't upgraded but I'm not really one to argue with a multi-billion dollar corporation.

Comment: It looks to me, though I may very, very well be mistaken, that IE9 is no longer supported on Windows 7, only IE11: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/microsoft-internet-explorer

Comment: browserstack.com may be useful to you. That's not my site, I'm just a user of their product.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, I'm running IE9 on my Windows 7 machine right now. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hVWddwo.png)

Comment: Google is your friend: `internet explorer 9 download` and I selected: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx Click Next..  Select: "Windows Internet Explorer 9 for IT Professionals and Developers--Windows Vista 64-bit Edition and Windows Server 2008 64-bit Edition"..  I would ignore the bit about Vista and download anyway..

Comment: @Leptonator already tried that. Received an error stating that it was the wrong version.

Comment: @JacobK That is weird - you are right.  I am going to probably get my hand slapped, but you could use the link from FileHippo.  I agree that Microsoft should have it available on their site.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Leptonator for the solution.

the link from FileHippo worked and installed on the users machine successfully with no malware.

http://filehippo.com/download_internet_explorer_windows_7_64/9458/

Comment: new link is correct

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful:

You can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test with most of IE versions. Installs as a separate program and allows to check from IE5.5 up to the latest (IE10 only on W8 machines).